# C# Show variables

Tags: c#

I'm starting with the C# language making console "apps". This one is to make grade averages. It doesn't show each name on each line with its own average that I still have to code. It works 100% until the //notation I've put
on the code. Under that I think it's the main problem, something that I might have forgotten to add or something.

```
namespace Repeat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("grade averages\n");
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.WriteLine("");

            float studentNumber;
            float testNumber;
            string name = "0";
            string test;
            float average = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Type the student number");
            float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out studentNumber);

            Console.WriteLine("Type the number of tests");
            float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out testNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int a = 1; a <= studentNumber; a++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Type the student name " + a + ":");
                nome = Console.ReadLine();
                for (int p = 1; p <= testNumber; p++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type the grade of test " + p + ":");
                    prova = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            //All above is working 100%

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("Students average:");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int a = 1; a <= studentNumber; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + ":" + average);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what's not working.

Comment: After typing the names and the grades, I want it to show in each line like:     name: average    //but it is showing only one name and not all the ones you type

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37015973/edit) your question to explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you read the names and test-results of the students, you overwrite the previous value. You should store the names and grades (and possibly do some averaging-calculations). One example would be to use a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` or `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, where the name is stored in the `Key`, and the grades are stored as a list in the `Value`.

The Dictionary class is from the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`.

Here is the [documentation for the Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A Dictionary is unordered. It may be better to do something like `class Student { public int Number { get; set; } public int Average { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }` and then use a `List<Student>` rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You're entering the names of the students and the test scores, but you need to save those values somewhere so that you can display them again.

This is just a basic example. You could add another class to your project like this:

```
public class StudentScoreCollection
{
    private List<float>() _testScores = new List<float>();
    public string StudentName {get;set;}
    public List<float> TestScores {get{return _scores}}
}
```

Then, in your main program, declare a variable like

```
var scores = new List<StudentScoreCollection>();
```

Each time you start with a new student name (inside the first `for` loop)
declare

```
var score = new StudentScore();
score.Name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then as each score is entered,

```
score.TestScores.Add(float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

(There's no validation here - it will blow up if they enter something that isn't a number.)

Then at the end,

```
scores.ForEach(score => Console.WriteLine(score.name + score.TestScores.Average());
```

I wrote that as a LINQ expression. That can be confusing at first. It's more readable as a `for-each` loop. This is the exact same thing:

```
foreach(var score in scores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(score.name + score.TestScores.Average();
}
```

Once you create a class that represents data that logically belongs together - like a name and a list of related scores - the rest becomes a little easier to work with.